# Python: List index out of range, but only sometimes

Tags: python, index-error

I am modifying some code that solves a Sudoku puzzle. I am adding in a piece that will randomly populate some of the empty cells will random values (1-9). It checks if this value is valid(not used in the current row, column, or 3x3 square) and, if it is, replaces the empty value with it.

The problem is I occasionally get an 'IndexError: list index out of range' while it is checking to see if the value is present in the current 3x3 square. I have printed the value and the current cell and have identified that the issue only happens when the column is the last or second-to-last (column 7 or 8). Below is the relevant code:

Here is where I generate 10 random values for random cells. I then use isValid to see if they are used in the current row, column, or 3x3 square.

```
    for c in range(10):
    e = random.randint(1,9)
    print(e)
    i = random.randint(0,8)
    j = random.randint(0,8)
    print([i],[j])
    if initial_grid[i][j] == 0:
        if isValid(initial_grid,i,j,e):
            initial_grid[i][j] = e
```

Here is the isValid function. The error is on the last if statement (if initial_grid[x][y] == e:), where is says the list index is out of range.

```
def isValid(initial_grid, i, j, e):
rowOk = all([e != initial_grid[i][x] for x in range(9)])
if rowOk:
    columnOk = all([e != initial_grid[x][j] for x in range(9)])
    if columnOk:
        secTopX, secTopY = int(3 *(i/3)), int(3 *(j/3))
        for x in range(secTopX, secTopX+3):
            for y in range(secTopY, secTopY+3):
                if initial_grid[x][y] == e:
                    return False
            return True
return False
```

The code works fine as long as one of the random values does not appear in the 7th or 8th column. The error is eliminated if secTopY+3 is replaced with secTopY+1, but then it will not check the 3x3 square properly.

I am failing to see where the list index is out of range. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `secTopX+3` and `secTopY+3` will be greater than `9` in those cases. So `initial_grid[x][y]` should fail in those cases

Comment: If that's the case, it is curious that the error only occurs when the column (relating to secTopY) is 7 or greater, while there is no issue for any value of the row.